# I am not able to get the root node data in the child loop in xsl coding from my xml

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath, xml-parsing

How to get the root node data in the child loop in xsl coding
Can you please throw some light as how to get the root node data in my child loop.
Or is there another way of doing this than below; appreciate your help.
**My XML**

```
<wd:Report_Data xmlns:wd="urn:com.workday.report/INT_Outbound">
    <wd:Report_Entry>
        <wd:Employee_ID>12345</wd:Employee_ID>
        <wd:LastName>Raj</wd:LastName>
        <wd:FirstName>Kiran</wd:FirstName>
        <wd:Dependents>
            <wd:Dependent_ID>D1245</wd:Dependent_ID>
            <wd:Dep_FirstName>Mahi</wd:Dep_FirstName>
            <wd:Spouse_LastName>Raj</wd:Spouse_LastName>
        </wd:Dependents>
        <wd:Dependents>
            <wd:Dependent_ID>D1256</wd:Dependent_ID>
            <wd:Dep_FirstName>Praveen</wd:Dep_FirstName>
            <wd:Spouse_LastName>Raj</wd:Spouse_LastName>
        </wd:Dependents>
        <wd:Benefits>
            <wd:Coverage>EE + Family</wd:Coverage>
        </wd:Benefits>
    </wd:Report_Entry>
</wd:Report_Data>
```

**My XSL CODE**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
   xmlns:wd="urn:com.workday.report/INT_Outbound" version="2.0">

    <xsl:output method="text" indent="no"/> 
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

        <xsl:variable name="NEWLINE" select="'&#xa;'"/>
        <xsl:variable name="COMMA" select="','"/>
        
    <xsl:template match="/">    

    <xsl:for-each select="wd:Report_Data/wd:Report_Entry/wd:Dependents">
    
            <xsl:value-of select="concat(wd:Report_Data/wd:Employee_ID,$COMMA)"/>           
            <xsl:value-of select="concat(wd:Report_Data/wd:LastName,$COMMA)"/>  
            <xsl:value-of select="concat(wd:Report_Data/wd:FirstName,$COMMA)"/>         
            
            <xsl:value-of select="concat(wd:Dependent_ID,$COMMA)"/> 
            <xsl:value-of select="concat(wd:Spouse_LastName,$COMMA)"/>              
            <xsl:value-of select="wd:Dep_FirstName"/>           
            
          <xsl:value-of select="$NEWLINE"/>
    
    </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**Current Output:**

```
,,,D1245,Raj,Mahi
,,,D1256,Raj,Praveen
```

**Expected Output:**

```
12345,Raj,Kiran,D1245,Raj,Mahi
12345,Raj,Kiran,D1246,Raj,Praveen
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your context is already `wd:Report_Data/wd:Report_Entry/wd:Dependents` so you need to go back up to `wd:Report_Entry` (with `..`) to get those values.

Updated XSLT...

```xml
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
   xmlns:wd="urn:com.workday.report/INT_Outbound" version="2.0">

    <xsl:output method="text" indent="no"/> 
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

        <xsl:variable name="NEWLINE" select="'&#xa;'"/>
        <xsl:variable name="COMMA" select="','"/>
        
    <xsl:template match="/">    

    <xsl:for-each select="wd:Report_Data/wd:Report_Entry/wd:Dependents">
    
            <xsl:value-of select="concat(../wd:Employee_ID,$COMMA)"/>           
            <xsl:value-of select="concat(../wd:LastName,$COMMA)"/>  
            <xsl:value-of select="concat(../wd:FirstName,$COMMA)"/>         
            
            <xsl:value-of select="concat(wd:Dependent_ID,$COMMA)"/> 
            <xsl:value-of select="concat(wd:Spouse_LastName,$COMMA)"/>              
            <xsl:value-of select="wd:Dep_FirstName"/>           
            
          <xsl:value-of select="$NEWLINE"/>
    
    </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Fiddle: http://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/6q1SDk2

Comment: Thanks Daniel, Can you help me on another improvement - How to achieve the results like below:
12345,Raj,Kiran,,,
12345,Raj,Kiran,D1245,Raj,Mahi
12345,Raj,Kiran,D1246,Raj,Praveen

Comment: I was able to do through two for loops , but just checking if any better way to do.  <xsl:for-each select="wd:Report_Data/wd:Report_Entry">     and another one     <xsl:for-each select="wd:Report_Data/wd:Report_Entry/wd:Dependents">

Comment: @Pradeep - You could do two separate template matches, but it probably won't give you any advantage over using two for-each's. Example: http://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/6q1SDk2/1